# Angular Rxjs repeatWhen: when all status are not COMPLETED

Tags: angular, rxjs

I want to retry(hit the same url upto 5 times with delay of 5sec) the same URL if I am not received all status are 'COMPLETED' in Angular Service file

````
[  
  {  
    "data": [   
      //SET OF OBJECTS  
    ],  
    "status": "COMPLETED"  
  },
  {  
    "data": [  
    //SET OF OBJECTS  
    ],  
    "status": "NO_DATA_FOUND"  
  }  
]```
````

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.http.get().pipe(
  map(res => {
   res.array.forEach(el => {
    if (el.status !== "completed") {
      //error will be catched by retryWhen
      throw res;
    }     
   })
   return res;
  }),
  retry(5),
  retryWhen(errors => errors.pipe(delay(1000)))
)
```

Comment: this will retry endlessly, it should be limited to 5 trials

Comment: retryWhen(attempts => zip(range(1, maxTries), attempts)
     .pipe(
       map(([i]) => i * i),
       mergeMap(i =>  timer(i * ms))
     )
   )
I think we need to include this in retryWhen blcok

Comment: its infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your code looks like, but I think this approach should work:

```js
src$.pipe(
  retryWhen(
    errSbj => errSbj.pipe(
      delay(/* ... */),
      take(5),

      // Until it receives a `COMPLETED` status
      takeUntil(statusCompleted$)
    )
  )
)
```

When `statusCompleted$` emits, the entire stream will `complete`.